# How to sort records by date property of string type in mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a records in mongo db as below :

```
 [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56840939e41a0038122b04c1"),
    "sudentName":"xxx",
    "payments" : [
            {
                    "paymentAmount" : 5000,
                    "paymentMode" : "Education",
                    "paidBy" : "Parent1",
                    "paymentDate" : "30-12-2015",
                    "paymentId" : ObjectId("5684097be41a0038122b04c2")
            },
            {
                    "paymentAmount" : 6000,
                    "paymentMode" : "Transport",
                    "paidBy" : "Parent1",
                    "paymentDate" : "30-12-2015",
                    "paymentId" : ObjectId("56840a54e41a0038122b04c3")
            },
            {
                    "paymentAmount" : 5000,
                    "paymentMode" : "Education",
                    "paidBy" : "Srinivas Nalla",
                    "paymentDate" : "19-01-2016",
                    "paymentId" : ObjectId("569e65cee51c46601bce3e1b")
            },
            {
                    "paymentAmount" : 5000,
                    "paymentMode" : "Education",
                    "paidBy" : "nalla",
                    "paymentDate" : "26-01-2016",
                    "paymentId" : ObjectId("56a6ea344d3111180cdeef5b")
            }
    ]
 }]
```

I am using the below query for the result to group the paymentAmount using studentName and recent paymentDate:

```
 db.students.aggregate([{$match:{studentName:"XXX"}},{$unwind:"$payments"},{$group:{_id:"$payments.paymentMode",paidDate:{$max:"$payments.paymentDate"},paidAmount:{$sum:"$payments.paymentAmount"}}}]);
```

this query is giving wrong result for the payment date as below:

```
   { "_id" : "Transport", "paidDate" : "30-12-2015", "paidAmount" : 6000 }
   { "_id" : "Education", "paidDate" : "30-12-2015", "paidAmount" : 15000 }
```

but i want the result as below:

```
    { "_id" : "Transport", "paidDate" : "30-12-2015", "paidAmount" : 6000 }
    { "_id" : "Education", "paidDate" : "26-01-2016", "paidAmount" : 15000 }
```

i don`t understood where is the problem in the query. I used $max operator for the payemtDate column.

Can any body help me?

Comment: Your paymentDate is stored as String. So $max operator will not work on it.

Comment: so, if i use max by paymentId then how can i get that paid date

Comment: What is the point doing with paymentId? I think you can do max by payment Date if you change the date format to YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: shall i keep paymentDate as string type or Date type?

Comment: It would be good if you keep date as Date type only.